# How do I make JS code: header { left : "title"} - Fullcalendar - to the right sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I register here yesterday and wanted to ask a little bit about Full calendar, that I just downloaded @ fullcalendar.io/download two days ago.

I want to put one of the codes in fullcalendar outside the frame.. exactly in the right sidebar

first Code JS, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today, prev,next'
    },
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true
});
```

second JS code, like this:

```
<div class="book-it-form">
            <form id="form1">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        if ($.cookie("book") != null && $.cookie("price") != null) {
                            var DateToday = $(document).ready(function(){  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({header: {left: "title"}}) });

                            var data = "";
                            data += "<div class='book-formtitle'>" + $.cookie("book") + "</div>" + "<div class='book-formprice'>" + $.cookie("price") + "</div>" + "<div class='book-list'>" + "</div>" ;

                            DateToday += "";

                            $("#lblData").html(data);
                            $.removeCookie("book");
                            $.removeCookie("price");

                            $("#lblDateToday").html(DateToday);
                        }
                    });
                </script>

                <span id="lblData"></span>
                <span id="lblDateToday"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**my question;**
how to keep my js code can successfully issue a header {left: "title"} on the right sidebar, because the code that comes out is always **[object object]**. more details, I attach a picture

print screen like this:
[please look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbMG1.jpg)

I hope to get many answers here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the title with [getView](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/getView/)

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
/* set */
$('#lblDateToday').html(view.title);
```

You may also want to check for the calendar navigation buttons being clicked to ensure the sidebar text gets updated as well

```
function updateLabel() {
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    $("#lblDateToday").html(view.title);
}
/* may want to be more selective on the button(s) that update? */
$('#calendar div.fc-toolbar button').on('click', updateLabel);
```

[image: jquery on click selector]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vumhmncu/

Comment: +1, I have tried in https://jsfiddle.net/vumhmncu/ and it worked well. Can i ask you for more selective: _$('#calendar div.fc-toolbar button').on('click', updateLabel);_ . I try in my code didn't work for this but in JsFiddle worked well. is there anything I must put another code? @smcd Previous thanks for the answer **smcd**

Comment: I used "#calendar div.fc-toolbar button" to find the buttons for the calendar to set click events. #calendar is the containing div and div.fc-toolbar was the div inside that contained the header, which contained 'button' elements, for which we want to get click notifications. I am unsure why it doesn't work for your code - post what you have? I added an image that shows what the on click is targeting.

Comment: Yes you are right,  I just misplaced some code "updateLabel" out of code #calendar function. @smcd thank you.